# optaplanner resolver problem similar to CFLP

Tags: optaplanner

A customer can be assigned to multiple servers, and a server can serve multiple customers, Customer has : demand, location , Server has : capacity, location, radius. how can I design the program by optaplanner9.4x?

I am trying to rewrite the flp project in optaplanner examples, and set two remaining shadow variable, I am little confused.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.